# Category Page Description Magento

Tags: category, category-page, category-description

This is my first time using magento, I was trying to edit the category page description.
site example: https://f31.sg/bedroom/bedframe/storage-bed.html
https://snipboard.io/jr6CyY.jpg

I can't seem to find the description section for me to edit it.

I tried going to Catalog > Categories, there is no WYSIWYG Editor that is containing the description and other page blocks.

Answer (score 0):

Open the Magento Admin,

1. `Catalog -> Categories` page.
2. Select particular Category
3. Check the `Content` section where you found `Description` options.

Comment: I follow your steps, there is a Description (WYSIWYG editor) but the description is not present on the editor.

https://snipboard.io/SPXo2R.jpg

Comment: Confirm, the text is show on category page is category description not another attribute or something else.

Comment: should I also check the backend to see where the category description is place? still can't find them on the frontend.

Comment: you need to check on frontend, is that description field or something else?

Comment: yes it's a description field

Answer (score 0):

It could be that the content that you are trying to edit is stored in a CMS block.

In the category's **Display Settings**, see if *Display Mode* is set to "Static block only" or "Static block and products".

If so, the static block is set in the category's **Content** section under *Add CMS Block*.